# About saving a model file in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm testing codes of Linear Support Vector Machines (SVMs) in below link:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-support-vector-machines-svms

I tested code with `spark-shell --master spark://192.168.0.181:7077`.

I modified last 2 lines like this:

```
model.save(sc, "file:///Apps/spark/data/mllib/testModelPath") 
val sameModel = SVMModel.load(sc, "file:///Apps/spark/data/mllib/testModelPath")
```

model.save ended with no error but when I tried to load that model it gives following message: 
INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 0 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection 
: 
:

When I tested without `file:///` , model saved to HDFS system, and I can load that model without error.

```
hadoop@XXX /Apps/spark/data/mllib/testModelPath/data> ll 

drwxrwxr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 2015-10-07 16:47 ./ 
drwxrwxr-x 4 hadoop hadoop 4096 2015-10-07 16:47 ../ 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop    8 2015-10-07 16:47 ._SUCCESS.crc 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop   16 2015-10-07 16:47 ._common_metadata.crc 
-rw-r--r-- 1 hadoop hadoop    0 2015-10-07 16:47 _SUCCESS 
-rw-r--r-- 1 hadoop hadoop  932 2015-10-07 16:47 _common_metadata
```

When I checked the folder after model saving, I found _metadata file is not created.

Dose anyone know the reason of this?

Comment: The model.save() function is really meant to be used with HDFS. If you save to the file system, each worker node will save a partition of the model locally, but the SVMModel.load() is unable to reassemble those local partitions. If you first call collect() before you save, you will be able to save the entire model on a single node, but again, when you try to load(), it will fail when a worker discovers there is no file on its local file system. 

Is there a reason you can't use HDFS?

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same problem. The problem is caused by save and load function. If you run spark in multi nodes, when you save the model, the spark save API just saves the corresponding partition on the node, so the model on every node is incomplete. But the load function's source code use the textFile API to load the model, and textFile needs that the file is same on every node. So it cause the problem. The method I solved it is save the model on HDFS, while it wastes the space.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)